# How to: SMS --> MySQL --> Flash?

Tags: mysql, flash, sms

This is question is about whether this will hypothetically work for a project I'm working on:

- Flash .swf plays in browser
- User sends SMS text message to SMS Server.
- SMS Server updates MySQL Database value.
- Flash connects to MySQL database and checks value.

Technically right now, I know I have to do research, but the biggest thing is "**Flash needs to do something once it hits X amount of SMS text messages**".  Anything that I can cut out of that process would be great, but I think that's the best way.

The SMS part is a mystery to me, but after looking at another post, it seems like with http://www.twilio.com/ or something similar I can have a MySQL database receive SMS data.

Getting Flash to connect to MySQL I've heard is possible, but that's not really the part I'm worried about.

Suggestions or tips?

Comment: What part *are* you worried about? This is a fairly broad question so some focus would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be broad, was worried about the entirety of SMS to Flash, MySQL happened to be inbetween.  I'm a designer with some programming experience, so lots of this is new and unexplored for me.  I wanted to know if anyone knew of problems I was going to run into, or better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash cannot connect to MySQL directly.
It can "ask" a server side programming language to though.
Basically you use HTTP or AMF remoting to connect to a PHP class or file which in turn interrogates the database.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the HTTP/AMF/PHP option.  I was guessing that Flash would need an intermediary between MySQL, just didn't know what.

Comment: It doesn't have to be PHP though, any server-side language that can access MySQL will do.